# Can I log and drop a packet in one iptables rule?

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, puppet

I've currently got the following [Puppet firewall](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/firewall) setup:

```
firewall { '100 drop insecure outgoing HTTP traffic':
  chain  => 'OUTPUT',
  dport  => 80,
  proto  => tcp,
  action => reject,
}
```

resulting in the following rule:

```
$ sudo iptables --list-rules OUTPUT | grep ^-A
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -m comment --comment "100 drop insecure outgoing HTTP traffic" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

It seems a common solution to log packets is to create separate log chains for each source chain and jumping to them, but that would at least double the complexity of this rule set and make it harder to follow the logic. Hence: **Is it possible log the packet in the same rule that drops it?**

Comment: Why not make a chain that logs & drops everything you send to it, then target several other individual rules to that chain whenever you want that action? You'd implement the log&drop subroutine just one, and each invocation of it would be a single line.

Comment: @Celada I would do that for a more complex setup, but for a single rule it would be good to keep it minimal.

Comment: I actually agree with you (and am going to upvote your answer in a sec) but you specifically asked for something that can be done in one rule (or I misunderstood).

Comment: Yeah, I just realised the answer might better have been part of the question. Should I move it?

Comment: No, I think it stands well alone. This comes up in practice often. Q: "How do I do this in one line". Best A is: "don't bother. use 2 rules. Unless you have millions of them and the size of the rule is an actual problem.".

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround using the iptables “LOG” extension. From `man 8 iptables-extensions`:

> This is a "non-terminating target", i.e. rule traversal continues at the next rule.  So if you  want  to  LOG the  packets  you refuse, use two separate rules with the same matching criteria, first using target LOG then DROP (or REJECT).

In Puppet:

```
firewall { '100 log insecure outgoing HTTP traffic':
  chain => 'OUTPUT',
  dport => 80,
  proto => tcp,
  jump  => 'LOG',
} ->
firewall { '101 drop insecure outgoing HTTP traffic':
  chain  => 'OUTPUT',
  dport  => 80,
  proto  => tcp,
  action => reject,
}
```

Or plain `iptables`:

```
$ sudo iptables --list-rules OUTPUT | grep ^-A
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -m comment --comment "100 log insecure outgoing HTTP traffic" -j LOG
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80 -m comment --comment "101 drop insecure outgoing HTTP traffic" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Not super clean, but at least it's simple.

Comment: For TCP I'd use `tcp-reset` rather than `icmp-port-unreachable`

Comment: I'm not sure that's controllable in Puppet - I simply specify the `reject` action and it seems to assume the rest.