# Can I log and drop packets with nflog in one iptables rule?

Tags: linux, iptables, logs

This is my rules about [ulogd](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) and [iptables](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/index.html), and records are stored in `/var/log/ulog/sysloemu.log`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1234 -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix 'example block'
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1234 -j DROP
```

I want to simplify this rules. I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1234 --nflog-prefix 'example block' -j DROP
```

out:

```
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--nflog-prefix"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information"
```

but [ebtables](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ebtables.8.html) accepts it (at least it doesn't give an error):

```
ebtables -A INPUT --protocol ipv4 --ip-proto tcp --ip-sport 1234 --nflog-prefix 'example block' -j DROP
```

Is there any way to put [NFLOG](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDG) (`--nflog-prefix`) inside the iptables rule so that there is only one line left?

PD: Or some other alternative to simplify these rules, except nftables

PD: I have many similar rules in my iptables script, so I would like a solution applicable to any rule

PD: There is a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349184/can-i-log-and-drop-a-packet-in-one-iptables-rule), but the solution is not what I am looking for

**Update:**

I have tried this (thanks to @Tom Yan):

```
# variable prefix
A='block A'
B='block B' # in this case i need to repeat the loop (and increase the number of lines)

iptables -N NFLOG_AND_DROP
iptables -A NFLOG_AND_DROP -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix "$A"
iptables -A NFLOG_AND_DROP -j DROP
# rules
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1234 -j NFLOG_AND_DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 1234 -j NFLOG_AND_DROP
```

But I can't add lines with different `--nflog-prefix` because I would have to repeat the sequence and my iptables script instead of reducing it, it would increase the number of lines (except someone propose some loop that solves this)

Comment: I wonder if you'll see `(legacy)` or `(nf_tables)` when you run `ebtables -V`.

Comment: at least it doesn't give an error

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can at most do something like this:

```
-N log_and_drop
-A log_and_drop -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix "shared prefix"
-A log_and_drop -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1234 -g log_and_drop
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 4321 -g log_and_drop
```

Assuming some of the (matching) rules are supposed to share an identical log prefix.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but if what you propose is to create new chains (LOG AND DROP), it is not what I want, however I would appreciate if you could give an example of how to apply this to several rules with different NFLOG outputs

Comment: The truth is, what you are after is exactly one of the reasons nftables exists. Btw, the reason that `--nflog-prefix` can be used with a target is because `nflog` is a matching extension instead of a target extension, which probably is in turn because ebtables (and arptables) was introduced in some sort of transitional period when nftables was already born. (Regardless whether that is true, AFAIK upstream already dropped the legacy userspace interface for ebtables and arptables, which means part of their rules are translated into nftables rules anyway, if you are not using a archaic version.)

Comment: I got it. So, since I can't use `--nflog-prefix` inside the rule, you could extend your answer with some example to enclose many rules inside a chain NFLOG_AND_DROP of NFLOG_AND_ ACCEPT to reduce the number of lines of my script (which is the intention of the question)? Thanks (PD: What does it mean `-g`)